# FTP connection information + warning lines appearing on the homepage of my campsite?

Tags: ftp

I've read lots of posts about this issue usually appearing in the backend of wordpress, but mine appears on the live website (a camp site, not to mention we are on a big period for online bookings !!!). I had no solution on the french forum, so I come here full of hope !

Issue :

For 3 days, my brother tells me that intermittently it appears at the top of the pages a window to fill in FTP credentials with the phrase: "to perform the requested action, wordpress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed ... ".

Below, full of warning lines that worry customers.

[image]

I saw on internet that a solution was to go to wp-config and insert:

```
define ('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
define ('FS_CHMOD_DIR', 0770);
define ('FS_CHMOD_FILE', 0660);
```

In my case, this made the page even more buggy. Even if I put the first line only, that I replace "direct" by "ftpext" or "ftpsockets" ... That I change manually CHMOD just for the files of wp-content etc ...

[image]

Note that I have not touched the site for 1 month, so nothing new on this side. The file quota on LWS is full but not the web space (regarding the warning message, if you wonder).

Thank you to those who can help me because it is very annoying for my brother's camping!

Comment: Just switching it to direct won't work, so you can remove those lines.

And the problem is right there in the error message "disk quota exceeded". It cannot write files, so it's falling down when trying to do so. Fix the underlying problem and free up some disk space or something.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Otto. Indeed, I was focusing on the ftp side of the issue, but after a backup, I've deleted some old files and I haven't seen these lines since. I hope it has solved the issue as you mentionned it. I will change my hosting service because I only use 6% of the space allocated, but I saw I'm very near to the max file quota, and wordpress is known to generate a lot of files ! I'll see in the coming hours and days if nothing happen, because last days it has shown intermittently.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a permissions issue. If you're running the website under apache on linux, make sure the group owner is www-data